# stuck on htaccess rewrite url

Tags: .htaccess

i've been stuck on this for a few weeks, i think i'm close now, but i'm stuck on syntax for htcaccess..

here's what i'm trying to do: user types in site.com and is redirected to subdomain.wordpresshost.com; however the address bar still says site.com (i also want to keep anything after this point such as/blog.html etc)

nameserver is all set, now i'm just rewriting urls... heres the best code i have come up with.. it's just not working

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.wordpresshost.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This code successfully changes subdomain.wordpresshost.com to site.com; however, it returns an error stating either 'server unavailable' or 'too many redirects'

I think i've hit my head against the keyboard so that I'm just making static noise, so i'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last `RewriteCond` is unnecessary and is creating the redirection loop - `www.site.com` is rewritten to `www.site.com`… maybe you meant the non-www. Either way, it needs to be removed.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.wordpresshost.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks Jason. I'd clearly been walking around in circles on this too long!